# Routes for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have my user_controller and the action create. I do however want to set a custom route to the create action so when the user hits `register` the create action sets the url to `user/thank-you`. I have added the following `match` to my `routes` file but the url stays unchanged after hitting the register button. Here is part of my routes file until the line with thank-you.

```
get '/:locale' => 'pages#home'
root :to => 'pages#home'


scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|es/ do

get "javascripts/dynamic_cities"
get "javascripts/dynamic_cities_to_stadia"
get "javascripts/dynamic_stadia"
get "javascripts/dynamic_modality_to_max_players"

get "tournaments/edit_info"
get "tournaments/seasons"
get "league_rosters/cancel_new"
get "tournament_administrations/cancel_new"

resources :admin_tasks, :only => [:index]
resources :sports
resources :countries
resources :cities
resources :stadia
resources :users
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :teams
resources :tournaments
resources :leagues
resources :brackets, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show]
resources :labs, :only => [:show, :edit]
resources :seasons, :only => [:edit, :show, :destroy]
resources :matches, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
resources :player_participations
resources :highlights

resources :users do
  resources :requests, :name_prefix => "user_"
end

# match 'league/:id/subscription' => 'league_rosters#new', :as => :subscription
match '/contact',  :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/terms_and_conditions', :to => 'pages#terms_and_conditions'
match '/about_us', :to => 'pages#about_us'
match '/cookie_excluder', :to => 'pages#cookie_excluder'
match '/vacancies', :to => 'pages#vacancies'
match '/signup',   :to => 'users#new'
match '/thank-you',   :to => 'users#create'
```

Here is also the create method in the `users_controller.rb`

```
def create
# Note: This function is repeated in request controller in the invitations part. So any change should be added to request controller aswell
@user = User.new(email: params[:user][:email].downcase,
                 name: params[:user][:name].capitalize,
                 password: params[:user][:password],
                 password_confirmation: params[:user][:password_confirmation],
                 language: params[:user][:language])
#for user_menu
@title = t("user.new.title")

if @user.save
  confirmation_code = "#{@user.id}#{random_string}"
  if @user.update_attributes(confirmation_code: confirmation_code)
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    vars = Hash.new
    vars[:cc] = "#{confirmation_code}"
    confirmation_url = url_maker(params[:request_protocol], params[:request_host_with_port], params[:request_locale], "#{email_confirmation_path}", vars)
    UserMailer.confirm_email(@user, confirmation_url).deliver
    sign_in @user
    @user_tournaments = current_user.tournaments.all(:order => "name ASC")
    @user_teams = current_user.teams.all(:order => "name ASC")
  else
    render 'new'
  end
else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

Is it possible for this to work the way I am approaching it or I will have to make a redirect and a `thank-you` page, which I can easily manage through my pages controller?

Comment: Can you paste your whole `routes.rb` file? Routes are matched by precedence so a previously defined route to create might be catching the request. Also, you should use POST for create (instead of match)

Comment: Hey @SergioLopezMendez, our app is quite big so I am not going to post the whole routes. I did however edit my initial post and included everything in the `routes` before the line which we are referring to.Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Can you also paste the `create` action in your users_controller.rb?

Comment: Just added it to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `thank-you` route above the resources block as follows:

```
...
get "league_rosters/cancel_new"
get "tournament_administrations/cancel_new"

# Move route here
match '/thank-you',   :to => 'users#create', via: [:post]

resources :admin_tasks, :only => [:index]
resources :sports
...
```

I'm also adding `via: [:post]` to the route since:

> Routing both GET and POST requests to a single action has security implications. In general, you should avoid routing all verbs to an action unless you have a good reason to.

[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html]